# An example such that $\mathrm{Ann}_R(\mathrm{Ann}_M(I))$ properly contains $I$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $I$ be an ideal of a ring $R$ and let $M$ be an $R$-module.

Recall 
$\mathrm{Ann}_M(I) = \{m \in M : am = 0 \;\;\forall a \in I\}$ and
$\mathrm{Ann}_R(N) = \{r \in R: rn = 0 \;\;\forall n \in N\}$, where 
$\mathrm{Ann}_M(I)$ is a submodule of $M$ and $\mathrm{Ann}_R(N)$ is a left-right ideal of $R$.

> Let $I$ be a right ideal of $R$ and let $N = \mathrm{Ann}_M(I)$. 
>   Although it is clear that $\mathrm{Ann}_R(N)$ contains $I$, what is an example such that $\mathrm{Ann}_R(N)$ does not equal $I$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** There is an easy example with $R=\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2)$. If you put effort into solving the question, but are still stuck, I can provide a hint for an ideal too.